# Document parent name lacks a collection id at index 53 in Firestore PHP SDK

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a subcollection in Google Firestore.  My goal is to get all records with a startDate (stored in Google Firestore's Timestamp data type) after January 1st, 1970.

I am using the GoogleCloud Firestore PHP SDK to do so:
http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v0.9.0/firestore/querysnapshot

Here is my code:

```
    $config = array(
        "projectId" => "xxx-test",
        "keyFile" => json_decode(file_get_contents("/xxx/firebase_auth.json"), true)
    );
    $firestore = new FirestoreClient($config);
    $collection = $firestore->collection("/clients/-LXXXXXX/trips");
    $query = $collection->where("startDate", ">=", new Timestamp(new \DateTime("Thu Jan 1st 1970")));
    var_dump($query->documents());
```

And I get this error:

```
    Exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\BadRequestException' with message 
    '{
        "message": "Document parent name \"projects\/xxx-test\/databases\/(default)\/documents\/\/clients\/-LXXXXXX\" lacks a collection id at index 53.",
        "code": 3,
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": []
    }'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collection pathing doesn't work that way:

```
$collection = $firestore->collection("clients")->document("-LXXXXXX")->collection("trips");
```